# Expressing "X of Y" or "Y's X"

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-german, expression

I came across this on some app for learning languages. Say I want to express "X of Y" or "Y's X". I saw that the app used the form

> der X des Y

not restricted to `der` but also `die` and `das`. I just wonder if this is the standard expression for this kind of things not associated with persons. For example the expression like "car's key", "key of the car".

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but if this is exactly how it was expressed in the application, it was completely wrong. Are you sure you didn't change something when shortening the example? Could you post a complete sentence from the app?

Comment: @rumtscho it's like "das Dach des Hauses". I apologize if I made a mistake on giving out the examples. I'm not really clear on all the grammar stuff...

Comment: "des" is correct, at least when the noun is masculine or neutral, "den" is not correct. Have you learned the genitive case yet?

Comment: @rumtscho just fixed my example. I'm not sure about that grammar name. Could you form an answer to that? Thank you so much!

Comment: When reading your question initially without the comments, I thought you were talking about mathematical functions. X an y are not the best choice in my view, I think a real example would make your question a lot more understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is one of the four cases in German, the genitive case. It is known as "Wes-Fall", because it is used in sentences which provide an answer to a "whose" question. To form the genitive for "the X of the Y", you follow the schema

> [article in Nominativ] X [article in Genitiv] Y+s

The articles in genitive are `des` for masculine and neutrum, `der` for feminine and plural. Also, this is the only of the four cases where you attach a suffix to all masculine and neutral nouns, this is why it is "des Hauses" and not "des Haus".

See for example http://german.about.com/library/blcase_gen.htm for a somewhat longer explanation (still targeted at learners, not linguists).